# how to link specific div content on another page in jquery?

Tags: html

I am having a drupal page called `mypage`, I want to navigate to another page  div from this page, I am using anchor tags for that but it still going to top of another page(sample-issue page).

The code I have : 
mypage :

```html
<div class="anchors" id="anchors-0">
    <span>sample page</span>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="https://mysite.dd:6123/sample-issue#anchor-0">issue1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="https://mysite.dd:6123/sample-issue#anchor-1">issue2</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

sample-issue page:

```html
<div class="content-area">

    <div class="field field--name-field-section-title field--type-string field--label-hidden field--item"><a name="anchor-0"></a>issue1</div>

    <div class="field field--name-field-text field--type-text-long field--label-hidden field--item"><p>issue 1 summary.</p></div>

</div>
<div class="content-area">

    <div class="field field--name-field-section-title field--type-string field--label-hidden field--item"><a name="anchor-1"></a>issue2</div>

    <div class="field field--name-field-text field--type-text-long field--label-hidden field--item"><p>issue 2 summary.</p></div>

</div>
```

Comment: You should add `id="anchor-0"`, in the other page (same-issue), rather thann adding name to the a tag.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.bg-blue {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  height: 100vh;
}

.bg-violet {
  background-color: blueviolet;
  color: white;
  height: 110vh;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Example Navigation</title>
</head>

<body>

  <a href="#violet-div">Goto Violet Div</a>

  <div class="container bg-blue" id="blue-div">
    <p>Blue Div</p>
  </div>

  <div class="container bg-violet" id="violet-div">
    <p>Blue Violet Div</p>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

The above code snippet is an example of what you are trying to achieve. You should give the `ID of the Div` you want to navigate to in the a tag.
`<a href="#violet-div">Goto Violet Div</a>`

And obviously, the div should have the same ID. 
`<div class="container bg-violet" id="violet-div"></div>`

In your specific case, it would be like:

`mypage:`

```html
<div class="anchors">
    <span>sample page</span>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="https://mysite.dd:6123/sample-issue.html#anchor-0">issue1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="https://mysite.dd:6123/sample-issue.html#anchor-1">issue2</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

`sample-issue:`

```html
<div class="content-area">

    <div class="field field--name-field-section-title field--type-string field--label-hidden field--item" id="anchor-0">
        <p>issue1</p>
    </div>

    <div class="field field--name-field-text field--type-text-long field--label-hidden field--item">
        <p>issue 1 summary.</p>
    </div>

</div>
<div class="content-area">

    <div class="field field--name-field-section-title field--type-string field--label-hidden field--item" id="anchor-1">
        <p>issue2</p>
    </div>

    <div class="field field--name-field-text field--type-text-long field--label-hidden field--item">
        <p>issue 2 summary.</p>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: i  tried this solution but it always going to top of the page, for me mine is two different pages not the same one

Comment: Please check whether there are Multiple same ID in the Page. ID is unique for a page. You should not use the ID multiple times in a single page. The above code should work fine if there is no other ID in the same name.